# How to manage unmanaged DLL on WebServer in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, dll, webserver, dllimport

As In my project I'm trying to import Dll but on adding reference, it showing me the error. I have searched in many blogs and found that my DLL is unmanaged.  So could you please let me know how can I convert my unmanaged DLL to managed DLL.

Comment: i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the .dll is neither an managed Assembly or COM object you need to utilize P/Invoke by using [DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).
Definitions for popular libraries can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/).